# Print a screen having ScrollView in android

Tags: android, printing, bitmap, screenshot

I am making an `APP` in which a `GridLayout` containing images is shown on screen along with a print button to get the whole `Layout` printed. For printing I am using following code:

```
 PrintHelper printHelper = new PrintHelper(this);
    printHelper.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
    printHelper.printBitmap("Print Bitmap", bitmap);
```

**The bitmap used above is get from following code:**

```
mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
mView.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mView.getDrawingCache());
mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

However I having trouble as above code only makes `Bitmap` of the the view shown on screen and not of the view that comes after scrolling page. I understand that it is impossible to make a screen shot of not-yet-rendered content. Then please suggest me what I need to do get print. Is there any other solution for printing other than the above method i used?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to using Scrollview.

```
 public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(ScrollView view) {
            Log.e("width", String.valueOf(view.getChildAt(0).getWidth()));
            Log.e("getHeight", String.valueOf(view.getChildAt(0).getHeight()));
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    view.getChildAt(0).getWidth(),
                    view.getChildAt(0).getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
            view.getChildAt(0).draw(c);

            return bitmap;
        }
```